# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]

Tags: android

I cann't to install android application on my Samsung Galaxy s4 text of error in the title;
When i tried to install via google play, i received  - "unknown error code during application install -24".

In logcat this errors:

```
Couldn't load memtrack module
package couldn't be installed in /data/app
```

Phone NOT ROOTED and therefore operation like "adb shell rm -rf /data/data/PACKAGE_NAME" doesn't work (permission denied).
I tried to clear phone cache also tried to find app in application manager - not helped.
Once i can to install, but second time alsu got error UID CHANGED;

p.s. cann't to change package name, because app placed in the google play

p.p.s sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me help:
uninstall/reinstall/install|app /reboot phone/clear cache - i did all that a certain time
after a some attempts app installed =)
A also tried to uninstall and reinstall - working nice

p.s. sorry for my english